# Is it possible to write protect old data of JSON Files and only enable appending?

Tags: javascript, java, python

I need to store some date stamped data in a JSON file. It is a sensor output. Each day the same JSON file is updated with the additional data. Now, is it possible to put some write protection on already available data to ensure that only new lines could be added to the document and no manual tampering should occur with it?

I suspect that creating checksums after every update may help, but I am not sure how do I implement it? I mean if some part of JSON file is editable then probably checksum is also editable.

Any other way for history protection?

Comment: Do you want to *prevent* tampering or *detect* it?

Answer (score 0):

Write protection normally only exists for complete files.  So you could revoke write permissions for the file, but then also appending isn't possible anymore.

For ensuring that no tampering has taken place, the standard way would be to cryptographically *sign* the data.  You can do this like this, in principle:

- Take the contents of the file.
- Add a secret key (any arbitrary string or random characters will do, the longer the better) to this string.
- Create a cryptographical checksum (SHA256 hash or similar).
- Append this hash to the file. (Newlines before and after.)

You can do this again every time you append something to the file.  Because nobody except you knows your secret key, nobody except you will be able to produce the correct hash codes of the part of the file above the hash code.

This will not *prevent* tampering but it will be *detectable*.

This is relatively easily done using shell utilities like `sha256sum` for mere text files.  But you have a JSON structure in a file.  This is a complex case because the position in the file does not correlate with the age of the data anymore (unlike in a text file which is only being appended to).

To still achieve what you want you need to have an age information on the data.  Do you have this?  If you provide the JSON structure as @Rohit asked for we might be able to give more detailed advice.